# How to close the sessions using Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-form-element

For eg:

```
http://example.com/login
```

Here is my site once I logged inside and uses User page `example.com/user` and when I log outside `www.example.com/logout` then the session is to be closed.

But if User did not logged in when anyone uses `example.com/user` the details should not come because I want the sessions to be closed and it should affect different browsers also.

How can it be done?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. As soon as some time has passed - the session is removed by GC automatically

Comment: @ Zerkms please can you give me a good link where I can learn this because i am new to this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zend session management](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html) has the option to [expire](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html) namespaces by 'hop' or time-based, you can also write lock the session via Zend_Session::writeclose or destroy it using Zend_Session::destroy() (ref: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html)

destroy():

> destroy(bool $remove_cookie = true, bool $readonly = true)
>   Zend_Session::destroy() destroys all of the persistent data associated with the current session. However, no variables in PHP are affected, so your namespaced sessions (instances of Zend_Session_Namespace) remain readable. To complete a "logout", set the optional parameter to TRUE (the default) to also delete the user agent's session id cookie. The optional $readonly parameter removes the ability to create new Zend_Session_Namespace instances and for Zend_Session methods to write to the session data store.

writeClose():

> writeClose($readonly = true)
>   Shutdown the session, close writing and detach $_SESSION from the back-end storage mechanism. This will complete the internal data transformation on this request. The optional $readonly boolean parameter can remove write access by throwing an exception upon any attempt to write to the session via Zend_Session or Zend_Session_Namespace.

Comment: I am using Zend_Session_Namespace

Comment: so you can use setExpirationSeconds or setExpirationHops, as I linked above: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html